# Parameterized DeleteAllByAttributes Doesn't Work in YII

Tags: yii

I am using the following code:

```
MyClass::model()->deleteAllByAttributes(array('phone_number'=>':phone_number'), '', array(':phone_number'=>$phoneNumber));
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
CDbException
SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables
does not match number of tokens. The SQL statement executed was:
DELETE FROM `my_class` WHERE `my_class`.`phone_number`=:yp0
(E:\xampp\htdocs\yii\db\CDbCommand.php:354)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I believe you don't need to bind the attributes in the `attributes` array (as in `findAllByAttributes()` too). The values in the `params` array are bound to values in the `condition` string, not the `attributes` array, so I believe the following should work for you (and be sanitized):

```
MyClass::model()->deleteAllByAttributes(array(
    'phone_number'=>$phoneNumber,
));
```

Alternatively, you could use:

```
MyClass::model()->deleteAllByAttributes(array(),'`phone_number` = :phone_number',array(
    ':phone_number'=>$phoneNumber,
));
```

Which would have the same effect... But then you might as well use `deleteAll()`:

```
MyClass::model()->deleteAll('`phone_number` = :phone_number',array(
    ':phone_number'=>$phoneNumber,
));
```

Comment: So there is no need to sanitize `$phoneNumber` beforehand. (except maybe a check if it's a valid phone number in this case)

Comment: Yes, from what I can see the values in the `$attributes` array are placed into a CDbCriteria `params` property in `CDbCommandBuilder::createColumnCriteria()` which is run as part of `deleteAllByAttributes()`, so no need to sanatize